# компилятор пишет функция ничего не выводит.как можно исправить код

Tags: php, функции

```
 function task17($n) {
   $sum =0;
   
   for ($j=0; $j <= $n; $j++) {
     if ($n % 3 == 0) { //если число делится без остатка на 3
       echo "$n<br>";  
     } else if ($n % 5 == 0) { //если число делится без остатка на 5
     //прибавьте это число к переменной $sum
       $sum += $n;}
     else if ($n % 3 == 0 && $n % 5 == 0) { //если число делится и на 5 и на 
       3
      $sum -=1;
    }
  }
  return  $sum; 
}
```

Comment: Приведите код в приличный вид.

Comment: @Эникейщик чуть исправил,я просто новичек еще,не совсем знаю как правильно

Comment: @Эникейщик  как думаете почему сругался компилятор? что тут не так в коде?

Comment: Сходу не вижу проблем. А какая задача? Довольно странный код. В проверках случайно не $j вместо $n должно быть?

Comment: @Эникейщик да вы были правы.Спасибо.

Comment: @Эникейщик надо как то сделать этот комент как ответ и поставить правильный , я так понял вам там балы начисляются за это

Comment: Да ладно, пусть так 

Answer (score 0):

Может, кому-то будет полезно мое замечание (на авторитетное мнение не претендую, т.к. в программировании новичок), но я считаю, что в программе на первое место нужно поставить проверку деления на 3 и на 5 в самый верх, т.к., например, при `j = 15`, сработает первый `if` и выполнит `echo "$n<br>";`, хотя, должно выполниться `$sum -=1;`.

В тестовом задании я сделал следующий код, который считаю более верным:

```
function task17($n){
    $sum = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        if ($i%5==0 && $i%3==0) {
            $sum -= 1;
        }
        elseif ($i%3==0) {
            echo "$i <br>";
        }
        elseif ($i%5==0) {
            $sum += $i;
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
```